# Switching through while loops in java

Tags: java, while-loop

I keep having trouble switching from one while loop to another.
here is my code:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

private static boolean test1 = false;
private static boolean test2 = false;

public static Scanner UI = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String testString;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    test1 = true;

    while(test1 = true){

        System.out.println("test1");
        testString = UI.nextLine();
        if(testString.equals("Hello World")){
            test1 = false;
            test2 = true;
        }
    }

    while(test2 = true){

        System.out.println("test2");
        testString = UI.nextLine();
        if(testString.equals("GOTO 1")){
            test2 = false;
            test1 = true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I think it has something to do with the test1 = true statement but I don't know if that's true. I want to be able to switch from one while loop to another and I don't want to do that with if statements.
I'm pretty new to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you will want to change your loop testing code and nest those loops as well -

```
test1 = true;
while (test1) {
  while(test1) { // <-- like that, not = true){
    System.out.println("test1");
    testString = UI.nextLine();
    if(testString.equals("Hello World")){
        test1 = false;
        test2 = true;
    }
  }
  while(test2) { // <-- like that, not = true){
    System.out.println("test2");
    testString = UI.nextLine();
    if(testString.equals("GOTO 1")){
        test2 = false;
        test1 = true; // <-- I assume that's what this was for.
    }
    // Note infinite loops now. test2 is only false with GOTO 1.
    // Which loops again.
  }
}
```

Because `==` is not `=`, and I assume you want the first loop to run again.

Comment: Ok, that solves my problem, if I did want to break out of the loop I would have to say that test1 = false correct?

Comment: @user3183679 yes. Or maybe a labeled break.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking for `(test1 = true)` and `(test2 = true)`, both of which will always return `true` as they are assignments for references `test1` and `test2` to value `true`, not comparisons.

Use `while (test1 == true)` or better, `while(test1)`.

In the current state of your code, the first `while` loop will loop forever, hence the second will never execute.

Comment: That fixes one part, but when you type in GOTO one it's not going to the first loop again.

Comment: @user3183679 of course not. Your execution is single-threaded and will not just switch back to the previous part of the code whatever you do with the booleans. I strongly suggest you refactor the design of your code without thinking by labels and `goto`s. You probably want to use a single `while` loop and different methods for different scopes in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try == instead of only = in your while statement...

Answer (score 0):

`while(test1 = true)` means you are asigning value to test1.
You try with `while(test1 == true)` or directly as `while(test1)` this will give you the comparison result as boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I think your aim is to switch between loop1 and loop2 depending on the received input string, but this will not work.

If you have switched from loop 1 to 2 you will never go back. If loop 2 is completed by receiving "GOTO 1" the program will exit.

Try to use one "control" loop and do the stuff depending on the keyword

```
boolean stop = false;
while(!stop){

    System.out.println("test1");
    String keyword = UI.nextLine();
    if(keyword.equals("loop1")){
        doLoop1Stuff();
    } else if (keyword.equals("loop2")) {
        doLoop2Stuff();
    } else if (keyword.equals("exit")) {
        stop = true; // program will exit
    }
}
```